# How to setup and use Python in Netbeans?

Tags: python, plugins, netbeans, ide

I have been through multiple videos on YouTube regarding setting up of Python in Netbeans but nothing seems to work. I am having Netbeans IDE 17 and Python 3.11.5. Can  anyone help me with setting up of Python in Netbeans?

I am expecting someone who knows latest setting up procedure for Python in Netbeans to answer or guide me with the steps to do so.

Comment: This isn't a help forum where you post a requirement to be met, and then wait for the responses. This site just doesn't work like that, and as it stands your question lacks focus. So update your question to provide details of a _specific problem_ you encountered when following the tutorials to use Python on NetBeans, along with supporting evidence that shows the problem.

Comment: In the tutorials it was said that I will be able to get the additional plugin file from Apache netbeans and it will be containing Zip files to be extracted, downloaded and plugged-in but now nothing so is happening. Rather there is a .nbm file to download now and further what is to be done?

Comment: Don't update your question in the comments. Instead, update the question itself **with the specific problem** you need to resolve, linking to the relevant tutorial. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Install from Netbeans. Tools -> Plugins -> Available Plugins -> Install.
Or Download the latest release and install in Netbeans: Tools -> Plugins -> Downloaded -> Add Plugins -> Install.

Comment: But to download the file to be used as plugin , now we are having .nbm file on Apache Netbeans website and after downloading it, what is to be done?